# Why this error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion?

Tags: c, pointers

Please have a look at the code, clang is giving me the error "incompatible pointer to integer conversion", why is it happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    char* name;
    name = malloc (sizeof(char) * 6);
    *name = "david";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whatever is happening is happening at this line:

```
*name = "david";
```

The type of `*name` would be `char`, as you are dereferencing the `char` pointed to by `name`. The type of `"david"` is `char[6]`, as it's a *string literal* of 6 chars (5 + null terminator). An array type *decays* into a pointer and a `char` is an *integral type*; your assignment tries to set a pointer to an integer, hence `incompatible pointer to integer conversion`.

Even if the left side of the assignment had the right type, you couldn't just copy arrays with the assignment operator. If you want to set `name` to `"david"`, then you should be using `strcpy( name, "david" )`.

Answer (score 10):

In C programming you can never copy/assign the string into a pointer directly like

```
*name = "david";
```

You can only copy a string using `memcpy()` (in built function).To fix the issue replace the line
 `*name = "david";` with `memcpy(name,"david",sizeof("david"));`

Comment: You should add +1 to the size for the case when name will contains something else than a bunch of zero: memcpy(name,"david",sizeof("david") + 1);

Comment: sizeof() function returns the size of the string along with terminating null character strlen() will not count the NULL character which will be present at the end of the string.So the Plus one after sizeof("david") is not required.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.  It has been so many years the last time that I've coded in C that I've now forgotten its basic principles.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
*name = "david";
```

should read

```
name = "david";
```

*name is synonymous (in this context) with name[0] (i.e. the first character of a string pointed to by the name variable). You want the name variable, not the contents of the pointer, to be assigned to point at the same thing that the string literal "david" is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

look here name is not a pointer to character
by using the library function malloc you have made it an array of characters
so you cannot simply point it to any address like a pointer
you have to use library function **strcpy(p,"david")**
then only it will give you desired results